# How to pinch to zoom listview in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a UI like image below and I cannot pinch to zoom it.
I wanna zoom it like Google Calendar. The video I pin to here [Link video zoom of Google Calendar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xwJyr-sOs5AuLh6QYNosWdtRYxt_BCi-/view?usp=sharing)

My UI:

[image: This is my UI]

I tried using `InteractiveViewer` but it's hard to zoom

Answer (score 1):

There is a package [zoom_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_widget). You can try.

Code sample :

```
 Zoom(
          maxZoomWidth: 1800,
          maxZoomHeight: 1800,
          child: Center(
            child:  pageContainer(),//youre widget
          )
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried but it is so hard to pinch. I must double tap screen to zoom. [this is demo]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MnOMM3zZcauzEMEzxhSn_JOKvFxdAn6c/view?usp=sharing